# Oracle transcation optimisation

Tags: oracle, rdbms

Is there any optimisation mechanism for transaction as a whole e.g.

1. delete from table1 with key 1
2. insert into table1 with key 1
3. commit

This could be internally converted into one update (which would probably allow to skip updating main index at least)

It's a silly way to write business logic, but sometimes it's done (at least in SAP).

Comment: `merge when match then update when not matched insert` ?

Comment: If the application issues a delete followed by an insert, there is no way for the database to "optimise" them together into a single update or merge, because it must treat each statement separately. You need to fix it in the application that's issuing the statements.

Comment: merge seems to be the right way to do it. can't comment on that answer (guess it's cause of formating) thanks